# Valor não está sendo gravado no banco

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, primefaces, hibernate

Tenho as seguintes entidades:

```
package br.com.pokemax.modelo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "habilidade", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "nome" }))
public class Habilidade {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NotBlank(message = "Nome não pode estar em branco.")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-z]*", message = "Atenção, digite somente letras")
    @Size(max = 20, message = "Máximo de 20 caracteres permitidos.")
    @Column(length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 150, message = "Máximo de 150 caracteres permitidos.")
    @Column(length = 150, nullable = false)
    private String descricao;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 150, message = "Máximo de 150 caracteres permitidos.")
    @Column(name = "texto_in_game", length = 150, nullable = false)
    private String textoInGame;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(length = 150, name = "efeito_secundario", nullable = true)
    private String efeitoSecundario;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne
    private Geracao geracao;

    public Habilidade() {

    }

}

package br.com.pokemax.modelo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "geracao")
public class Geracao {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NotBlank(message = "Nome não pode estar em branco.")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-z]*", message = "Atenção, digite somente letras")
    @Size(max = 20, message = "Máximo de 20 caracteres permitidos.")
    @Column(length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Min(1)
    @Max(7)
    private Integer numero;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "total_pokemons", nullable = false)
    private Integer totalPokemons;

    public Geracao() {

    }

}
```

O seguinte Controller:

```
package br.com.pokemax.controle;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import br.com.pokemax.modelo.Geracao;
import br.com.pokemax.modelo.Habilidade;
import br.com.pokemax.negocio.GeracaoDAO;
import br.com.pokemax.negocio.HabilidadeDAO;
import br.com.pokemax.util.MensagensUtil;
import br.com.pokemax.util.ValidadorUtil;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "habilidademb")
public class ControleHabilidade implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Habilidade habilidade;

    @Inject
    private HabilidadeDAO dao;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Boolean efeitoSecundario;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private List<Habilidade> lista;

    @Inject
    GeracaoDAO gDao;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Geracao geracao;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private List<Geracao> geracoes;

    @PostConstruct
    public void inicio() {

    }

    public void novo() {
        habilidade = new Habilidade();
    }

    public void gravar() {
        try {
            if (habilidade.getId() == null) {
                dao.insert(habilidade);
                MensagensUtil.msg("Info", "cadastro.sucesso", new Object[] { MensagensUtil.get("habilidade") });
                habilidade = new Habilidade();
            } else {
                dao.update(habilidade);
                MensagensUtil.msg("Info", "alterado.sucesso", new Object[] { MensagensUtil.get("habilidade") });
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
            return;
        }

    }

    public void pesquisar() {
        try {
            lista = dao.findAll();
            for (Habilidade habilidade : lista) {
                habilidade.setDescricao(ValidadorUtil.checkTipoPokemon(habilidade.getDescricao()));
                habilidade.setTextoInGame(ValidadorUtil.checkTipoPokemon(habilidade.getTextoInGame()));
                habilidade.setDescricao(ValidadorUtil.checkAtributoPokemon(habilidade.getDescricao()));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void excluir(Habilidade h) {
        try {
            dao.delete(h);
            MensagensUtil.msg("Info", "removido.sucesso", new Object[] { MensagensUtil.get("habilidade") });
            pesquisar();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public void editar(Long id) {
        try {
            setHabilidade(dao.find(id));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

    }

    public void cancelar() {
        habilidade = null;

    }

    public List<Geracao> listarGeracoes() throws Exception {

        this.geracoes = gDao.findAll();
        return this.geracoes;
    }

}
```

Estou implementando um autoComplete que está assim:

```
<p:autoComplete id="geracao" value="#{habilidademb.geracao}" completeMethod="#{habilidademb.listarGeracoes()}"
                        dropdown="true" var="bean" itemLabel="#{bean.nome}" itemValue="#{bean}" converter="geracaoConverter"/>
```

E meu Converter:

```
package br.com.pokemax.modelo.converter;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

import br.com.pokemax.modelo.Geracao;
import br.com.pokemax.negocio.GeracaoDAO;

@FacesConverter(value = "geracaoConverter", forClass = Geracao.class)
public class GeracaoConverter implements Converter {

    GeracaoDAO dao = new GeracaoDAO();

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String value) {
        try {
            Geracao d = dao.find(Long.parseLong(value));
            return d;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object object) {
        if (object != null) {
            return String.valueOf(((Geracao) object).getId());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Quando clico no autocomplete, ele mostra as Gerações, porém quando eu seleciono e mando gravar, ele não grava a **geracao_id** no banco. Debugando eu percebi que o objeto geracao está indo null, alguém sabe como posso resolver ?

Estou com o erro:

> 18:27:50,276 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 18:27:50,277 ERROR [stderr] (default
>   task-6)   at
>   br.com.pokemax.modelo.converter.GeracaoConverter.getAsObject(GeracaoConverter.java:28)
>   18:27:50,277 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.getConvertedValue(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:670)
>   18:27:50,278 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1045)
>   18:27:50,278 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:975) 18:27:50,278
>   ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1248)
>   18:27:50,278 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
>   18:27:50,278 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
>   18:27:50,278 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
>   18:27:50,279 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   org.primefaces.component.panel.Panel.processValidators(Panel.java:299)
>   18:27:50,279 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
>   18:27:50,279 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
>   18:27:50,279 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
>   18:27:50,279 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
>   18:27:50,280 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
>   18:27:50,280 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) 18:27:50,281
>   ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)   at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>   18:27:50,282 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
>   18:27:50,282 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>   18:27:50,284 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>   18:27:50,285 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>   18:27:50,285 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>   18:27:50,285 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   18:27:50,286 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>   18:27:50,286 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>   18:27:50,286 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   18:27:50,286 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>   18:27:50,286 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>   18:27:50,286 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>   18:27:50,286 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>   18:27:50,287 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>   18:27:50,287 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>   18:27:50,287 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   18:27:50,287 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>   18:27:50,287 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   18:27:50,287 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   18:27:50,287 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>   18:27:50,287 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>   18:27:50,287 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>   18:27:50,288 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>   18:27:50,288 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>   18:27:50,288 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>   18:27:50,288 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>   18:27:50,288 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>   18:27:50,288 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>   18:27:50,288 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>   18:27:50,288 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>   18:27:50,289 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>   18:27:50,289 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>   18:27:50,289 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>   18:27:50,289 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>   18:27:50,289 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
>   18:27:50,290 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
>   18:27:50,290 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   18:27:50,290 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   18:27:50,290 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 2):

Vou deixar também uma implementação de um conversor genérico muito bom. Nós usamos um semelhante na empresa. A vantagem é que não é necessário buscar em um BD, o objeto fica gravado no próprio componente.

```
public class SimpleEntityConverter implements Converter {  

public Object getAsObject(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component, String value) {  
    if (value != null) {  
        return this.getAttributesFrom(component).get(value);  
    }  
    return null;  
}  

public String getAsString(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component, Object value) {  

    if (value != null  
            && !"".equals(value)) {  

        BaseEntity entity = (BaseEntity) value;  

        // adiciona item como atributo do componente  
        this.addAttribute(component, entity);  

        Long codigo = entity.getId();  
        if (codigo != null) {  
            return String.valueOf(codigo);  
        }  
    }  

    return (String) value;  
}  

protected void addAttribute(UIComponent component, BaseEntity o) {  
    String key = o.getId().toString(); // codigo da empresa como chave neste caso  
    this.getAttributesFrom(component).put(key, o);  
}  

protected Map<String, Object> getAttributesFrom(UIComponent component) {  
    return component.getAttributes();  
}  

}
```

Fonte: http://www.rponte.com.br/2008/07/26/entity-converters-pra-da-e-vender/

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisando, descobri que pro `Inject` funcionar no converter é preciso usar o `@Named` ao invés do `@FacesConverter`, meu converter ficou assim:

```
@Named(value = "geracaoConverter")
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531449/cdi-injection-into-a-facesconverter

Answer (score -1):

Não faltou o `@Inject` do `GeracaoDAO` no Converter? Tente debugar o converter para ver se os retornos estão corretos.

Comment: Eu estava trabalhando na hora do almoço, acredita que depois que voltei ao trabalho fiquei pensando nisso ? Ou seja, estava convicto, em casa vou testar e te falo, obrigado.

Comment: Muito estranho, o dao ainda continua null. :(

Comment: Ele não está passando desta linha: `Geracao d = dao.find(Long.parseLong(value));`

Comment: Vc não gostaria de tentar um conversor genérico? Tem um conversor muito bom que serve para a maioria dos casos (SimpleEntityConverter) http://www.rponte.com.br/2008/07/26/entity-converters-pra-da-e-vender/

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o meu erro

Comment: Agora passou no converter, porém o atributo geracao está indo como null.

Comment: Vc disse que o dao está null ou o resultado dele?

Comment: Ele está null quando chego no método getAsObject.

Comment: Talvez ele não possa ser injetado no converter. Não tenho certeza. Aconselho fazer um teste com esse SimpleEntityConverter, ele grava os dados no próprio componente. No caso da sua classe, acho que funciona sem problemas pois ela tem o getId().

Comment: Consegui, vou postar a resposta.

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado pelo retorno.