# Objeto injetado mas está null

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, nullpointerexception, cdi

Tenho um objeto que é injetado no meu converter :

```
package br.com.pokemax.modelo.converter;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import br.com.pokemax.modelo.Geracao;
import br.com.pokemax.negocio.GeracaoDAO;

@FacesConverter(value = "geracaoConverter", forClass = Geracao.class)
public class GeracaoConverter implements Converter {

    @Inject
    GeracaoDAO dao;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String value) {

        if (value != null) {
            try {
                Geracao geracao = dao.find(Long.parseLong(value));
                return geracao;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e;
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object object) {
        if (object != null) {
            return String.valueOf(((Geracao) object).getId());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Eu observei que em outras classes este dao já é instanciado, mas no converter ele está null e por conta disso, meu código não passa da linha:

```
Geracao geracao = dao.find(Long.parseLong(value));
```

E estoura o erro `NullPointer`, alguém sabe como posso resolver ?

Pergunta relacionada: [Valor não está sendo gravado no banco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167606/valor-n%c3%a3o-est%c3%a1-sendo-gravado-no-banco/167618?noredirect=1#comment345235_167618)

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisando, descobri que pro `Inject` funcionar no converter é preciso usar o `@Named` ao invés do `@FacesConverter`, meu converter ficou assim:

```
@Named(value = "geracaoConverter")
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531449/cdi-injection-into-a-facesconverter